# How to ask systemd why a service was stopped

Tags: systemd

I would like to know why a given service was stopped. I can think of several reasons:

- The service crashed
- The service exited by itself
- The service was explicitly stopped through `systemctl stop`
- The service was explicitly killed through `systemctl kill`
- The service was `PartOf` another service that was stopped
- The service was in conflict with another service that was started.

I am sure there are others I am forgetting.

Is there a way to ask systemd what caused a service to stop?

Comment: have you since been able to progress on this question Noé? I am faced with the same problem: when updating the `docker` package a `systemctl stop docker; systemctl start docker` gets executed. That will `systemctl stop containers` because of `Require: docker.service` and `systemctl start docker` will not restart the containers because they were explicitly stopped. I'd like to find out that the containers were stopped because of `Requires=docker` and to restart them on docker's start.

Comment: same question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421752/how-to-find-why-a-systemd-service-was-stopped

Comment: Nope. As far as I can tell there is nothing provided by systemd to know why a service stopped.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

To check the service status:

```
# systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:httpd.service(8)

Feb 25 06:56:00 docker systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 25 06:56:00 docker systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 25 06:56:00 docker systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 25 06:56:32 docker systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 25 06:56:32 docker httpd[18908]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::5054:ff:fef5:a1f5%enp1s0. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Feb 25 06:56:33 docker httpd[18908]: Server configured, listening on: port 80
Feb 25 06:56:33 docker systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 25 07:02:15 docker systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 25 07:02:16 docker systemd[1]: httpd.service: Succeeded.
Feb 25 07:02:16 docker systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
```

To check the log of the service(journalctl --unit=service_name):

```
# journalctl --unit=httpd
Feb 25 06:56:00 docker systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 25 06:56:00 docker systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 25 06:56:00 docker systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 25 06:56:32 docker systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 25 06:56:32 docker httpd[18908]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::5054:ff:fef5:a1f5%enp1s0. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Feb 25 06:56:33 docker httpd[18908]: Server configured, listening on: port 80
Feb 25 06:56:33 docker systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 25 07:02:15 docker systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 25 07:02:16 docker systemd[1]: httpd.service: Succeeded.
Feb 25 07:02:16 docker systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: I'm sorry but those are basic systemd commands and do not answer the question, unless you can point to what specifically in these command's output may be used to determine the cause of the service stopping.

Comment: FWIW I'm pretty sure there is no satisfactory answer to this question. ([See my similar question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421752/how-to-find-why-a-systemd-service-was-stopped)). Maybe systemd doesn't track this information at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can get more details using:

```
systemctl show <service_name>
```

Comment: What in particular here?